# What's the wattage of the heater

Tags: electrical

I have an in-wall heater with this label attached:
[image: heater sticker]
How come it has 4 different currents/wattages listed? Which one applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be instructions available on how to wire the elements inside the heater to obtain any of the nameplate wattages -- this heater has multiple elements which can be wired in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

It has four different settings. Low,med-low,med,high?

The highest one applies for conductor and breaker sizing.

Comment: Different "settings" is kind of a confusing way to put it. It will put out one of four different wattages according to how you wire it. There will be a wiring diagram somewhere on the unit or in the instructions.

Comment: Actually, I was figuring the unit had a selector switch for output. Like any hair dryer draws different current for different settings. The OP didn't post a picture of the front of it.

Comment: I've wired many of these, and even have two toe-kick heaters like this in my bathrooms. Some have two wattages, some four. It's all in how you wire it. They have multiple elements, and you wire some in parallel and some in series to get the combination of wattage you want.

Comment: I think Speedy should post as an answer, this is how the multi voltage units list the wattage depending on how they are wired

Comment: Mine does not have any switches on it and powered only by two wires. I will check for the availability of alternative wiring when I get home.

Comment: Yup, @SpeedyPetey was right, there are bunch of terminals on the side that allow to use smaller amount of heating elements.

Comment: Interesting. Speedy has schooled me on this. I have never seen a multi watt heater like that. Would seem to be overkill to make a heater with different wattages but must be for different size rooms and to control how fast it heats up. I guess you get to choose how much heat you want.